# Using pdftotext in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

The laptop provided by my German research institute broke down and I am now using a new laptop provided by my Dutch institute, but I have not set up Python and Jupyter Notebook yet. This is why I wanted to run code in **Google Colab** but realise that the [`pdftotext`](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/) Python package cannot be installed.

Using  `!pip install pdftotext`  or `!apt-get install` both result in this error notification:

`E: Unable to locate package pdftotext`

I assume that I am missing dependencies. Is there any way can make this work in Google Colab, or will I need to run my code elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Per the README on pdftotext on [GitHub](https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext), there are additional dependencies that need to be installed before you can install the package.

1. Update the packages within the Google Colab session then download the required packages.

```
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt install build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config python3-dev
```

2. Next install pdftotext with pip.

`!pip install pdftotext`

3. Finally test out that the package is working correctly. Below is a codeblock from the package's repo.

```
import pdftotext

with open("your_pdf.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

for page in pdf:
    print(page)
```